# JavaScript - function in for loop not performing as expected

Tags: javascript, splunk

I am building a dashboard that graphs some data. Using splunk js charts to display the data.

My problem is not with the charting. But I would suspect my logic.

What is happening:

1. Client - requests chart data from server
2. Server - returns this object:

a

```
Object { splunkResults: Array[3], 
metricHTML: "<div id="MetricOne" class="metric"><p class="lead"…s="metric">
<p class="lead">Metric Three</p></div>", metricID: Array[3]}
```

1. Client - model.js calls view.insertMetricContainers via callback and inserts object.metricHTML into the correct container
2. Client - model.js calls view.graphsReady in for loop via callback and creates a chart and inserts it into the correct metric div based on object.metricID[i]
3. Client - charts are displayed

My problem is that only one of the charts is being displayed, the first one.

If you look at this function in view.js:

```
splunkjs.UI.ready(chartToken, function() {});
```

I have a console.log("test"); Which is only printed once.

What is my mistake here?

Let me know if I can provide any more information, I have tried a few approaches and have run out of ideas.

**Model.js**

```
dashboard.getSystemMetrics = function(callback) {
    var url = "/services/systemMetrics/?";
    if (dashboard.url[1]) {
        url = url + dashboard.url[1];
    }
    if (dashboard.limit) {
        url = url + "&limit=" + dashboard.limit;
    }

    $.get(url, function(response) {
        callback(response.metricHTML, null);

        for (var i = 0; i < response.splunkResults.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            callback(null, response.splunkResults[i], response.metricID[i]);
        }
    });
};
```

**View.js**

```
view.graphsReady = function (data, id) {
    console.log(id);
    var chart = null;
    var chartToken = splunkjs.UI.loadCharting('/javascripts/splunk.ui.charting.js', function() {
        // Once we have the charting code, create a chart and update it.
        chart = new splunkjs.UI.Charting.Chart($("#" + id), splunkjs.UI.Charting.ChartType.AREA, false);
    });

    splunkjs.UI.ready(chartToken, function() {

        chart.setData(data, {
            "chart.stackMode": "stacked",
            "legend.placement": "top",
            "axisTitleX.text": "Time",
            "axisTitleY.text": "Data"
        });
        chart.draw();
    });
};
```

**Controller.js**

```
$(function(){
    // Grab user params
    dashboard.url = window.location.href;
    dashboard.url = dashboard.url.split("/?");
    dashboard.limit = "day";
    // Get Service Statuses
    //dashboard.getQuickStatus(controller.quickStatusReady);

    // TODO listener events
    dashboard.getSystemMetrics(controller.systemMetricsReady);
});



controller.systemMetricsReady = function(html, data, id) {
    if (html) {
        view.insertMetricContainers(html);
    } else if (data && id) {
        view.graphsReady(data, id);
    }
};
```

If you would like to suggest a better question title, please by all means go ahead.

EDIT - i have checked the logs yes. No errors, I wouldn't ask the question if I had errors.

I did a console.log in the set data function (view.js) and it was only logged once not 3 times like it should have. Although the function graphReady is called 3 times

**UPDATE** - I have found in the view.js code that this function is only run once. Despite the function view.graphsReady being called 3 times.

```
var chartToken = splunkjs.UI.loadCharting('/javascripts/splunk.ui.charting.js', function()   {
    // Once we have the charting code, create a chart and update it.
    chart = new splunkjs.UI.Charting.Chart($("#" + id), splunkjs.UI.Charting.ChartType.AREA, false);
    console.log(chart);
});
console.log(chartToken);
```

So, chartToken is printed 3 times. chart however is only printed once.

Comment: Did you check the `console` for errors?

Comment: I assume that the JSON object has the `"` of the HTML code properly escaped, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes that was just a console.log(object); then copy paste from the console.

The code executes without errors, all the objects are valid JSON. so object.splunkResults has 3 arrays, all for separate charts. This function is only run once in view.js. Hence why only one chart is displayed

splunkjs.UI.ready(chartToken, function() {
        chart.setData(data, {